# Russian characters are returned in bad charset

Tags: elasticsearch, character-encoding

On my Centos 7 workstation i have elasticsearch (ver.5.5.1) service by image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.1.

Filesystem type on my workstation is xfs.

I have .tar archive with /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/ contains index structure:
(JSON from kibana)

```
{
  "_index": "fias-addrobj",
  "_type": "document",
  "_id": "00173aad-ae1a-413e-b73c-d9e573923ef9",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "aoid": "00173aad-ae1a-413e-b73c-d9e573923ef9",
    "formalname": "Ð£Ñ‡Ð¸Ñ‚ÐµÐ»ÑŒÑÐºÐ¸Ð¹",
    "regioncode": "26",
    "offname": "Ð£Ñ‡Ð¸Ñ‚ÐµÐ»ÑŒÑÐºÐ¸Ð¹",
    "shortname": "Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾ÐµÐ·",
    "aolevel": 7,
    "parentguid": "2a1c7bdb-05ea-492f-9e1c-b3999f79dcbc",
    "aoguid": "1a10726e-c22d-4ed0-b01e-ebe7bce46ddf",
    "actstatus": 1
  }
}
```

Start log my JVM arguments:

> JVM arguments [
>           -Xms2g, -Xmx2g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC,
>           -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75,
>           -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly,
>           -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m,
>        -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,
>        -Djna.nosys=true,
>   -Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true,
>   -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true,
>   -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true,
>   -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false,
>        -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true,
>        -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true,
>        -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,
>        -Des.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/,
>        -Xms512m, -Xmx512m, -DFile.encoding=UTF-8,
>        -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch
>           ]

**Trouble with formalname – string, offname – string, shortname – string wrong charset.**

Comment: Success!
The problem was in the wrong encoding of the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to help you but I don't have much reputation, so I can't write comment...

Anyway, I also have many experience "Charset" is not matched.
so, I think that you have to one more test which is modify JVM options.

I found two documents that related in Java options below.

> doc1.
> link : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setting-system-settings.html
>
> doc2.
> link : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html

Two documents are modify other option for staring elasticSearch, but JVM options are not depends on elasticSearch.
So, I think that is not worthless for try to run.

> ES_JAVA_OPTS="-dFile.encoding=UTF-8" ./bin/elasticsearch

or

> export ES_JAVA_OPTS="-dFile.encoding=UTF-8" ./bin/elasticsearch